# Mocha skips a number of tests

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, mocha.js

I have the following test (whose values have been changed due to corporate policy), but for whatever reason Mocha will not run it. What is weirder, if I change `test` to `test.only`, Mocha does run it but - as one would expect - none of my other tests. I added some `console.log`s describing what does get run versus what does not. Has anyone seen anything like this?

The code:

```
/*global suite, setup, teardown, test, require, console */
var expect = require('expect.js'),
    sinon = require('sinon'),
    proxyquire = require('proxyquire');

suite('seven', function () {
    'use strict';

    var one = {
        a: sinon.stub()
    };

    var two = {
        b: sinon.stub()
    };

    var three = {
        c: sinon.stub()
    };

    var four = proxyquire(
        './four.js',
        {
            'one.js': one,
            'two.js': two
        }
    );

    var five = proxyquire(
        './five.js',
        {
            './four.js': four
        }
    );

    var six = proxyquire(
        './six.js',
        {
            './five': five
        }
    );

    var seven;

    setup(function () {
        console.log('does not print');

        seven = proxyquire(
            './seven.js',
            {
                './three.js': three,
                './six.js': six
            }
        );
    });

    suite('d', function () {
        console.log('does print');

        test('d things', function () {
            console.log('also does not print');

            var expectedDValue = 'd value';

            one.a.callsArgWith(1, {
                'dKey': expectedDValue
            });

            two.b.callsArgWith(1, true);

            three.c.returns({
                'cKeyOne': 'cValueOne',
                'cKeyTwo': {
                    'subCKey': 'subCValue'
                }
            });

            return seven.d().then(function (dValue) {
                expect(dValue).to.be(expectedDValue);
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Mocha is being run via `make` with these relevant lines:

```
TEST_TIMEOUT    := 5000
MOCHA_REPORTER  := dot
MOCHA_UI        := tdd
SERVER_PATH     := js
MODULE_PATH     := $(realpath ./)/node_modules/.bin

MOCHA_COMMAND := $(MODULE_PATH)/mocha
SERVER_TEST_FILES := $(shell find $(SERVER_PATH) -name "*.test.js")
MOCHA_SETUP_FILE := $(shell find $(SERVER_PATH) -name "mochaSetup.js")

test:
    -@$(MOCHA_COMMAND) -u $(MOCHA_UI) -t $(TEST_TIMEOUT) -R $(MOCHA_REPORTER) $(MOCHA_SETUP_FILE) $(SERVER_TEST_FILES)
```

**UPDATE**

I have found that out of ~1600 tests only ~900 of them are being run. Mine being new is purely a coincidence. The test files are being read - if I `console.log` inside of the `suite` functions I see them printed - but neither the `setup` nor `test` functions are being executed. I confirmed they are not being executed on a coworker's machine either, but the are being executed in our CI environment.

**UPDATE 2**

It seems the problem may be limited to the Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL) - another coworker running a VM on Windows 7 sees all of the tests run.

Comment: The code you posted does in fact run the test, so I imagine the problem is in some code that you haven't posted.

Comment: Also, potentially relevant. Which version of mocha are you using?

Comment: Would the problem be in the running code, then? I am not sure what other code to post since that is the entire contents of the file sans proper names and values. Mocha version is 1.21.4 which I understand is really old, but I am not allowed to upgrade anything without corporate clearing it.

Comment: Honestly I'm not sure. I copied your code into a file, installed all of your dependencies (including mocha@1.21.4), made blank JS files for the modules you proxyquire, and it runs just fine. :\

Maybe share the command you're using to run mocha?

Comment: Edited my question with the Makefile snippet running the tests.

Comment: Sadly I'm still unable to reproduce the problem. :\ Perhaps double-check that your code really is the same aside from the name changes. Otherwise the problem is probably something in one of the other test files or `mochaSetup.js` interfering with test discovery. Its the only way I can imagine switching to `only` would allow you to still run the test, since it could cause that interfering code to be skipped.

Comment: @sripberger I added some more details related to the latest findings. I am not sure if you are experienced with WSL, but that seems to be a factor in this problem.

Comment: Interesting. Yeah I don't have any experience with that, so sorry, it doesn't seem like I can help. Best of luck, though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns a low-level exception raised in another test caused Mocha to stop running tests completely. In specific, one of my tests was trying to perform a file operation that WSL's file system does not support, but instead of giving me any indication of what was happening Mocha just quit.

It is not a great process, but my advice to anyone else having this problem is find the last test run before Mocha quits and manually check for low-level errors.